# Help installing GZDoom (Kubuntu)

Tags: command-line, bash, kubuntu

So, because I slapped Kubuntu on a trashy laptop, I of course want to play doom. So I google around, trying to find the least intimidating-looking post (know nothing about the bash stuff yet) and I see [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/9ifkwo/gzdoom/) that says:

```
wget -O- http://debian.drdteam.org/drdteam.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://debian.drdteam.org/ stable multiverse'
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gzdoom
```

So I run these commands, but when it tries to install the repository it tells me that the repo is "unsigned" and because its "insecure" it wont install because the option to install insecure repos is disabled by default.

So, I try and find a way around this and I find [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/1331936/how-can-i-get-past-a-repository-is-not-signed-message-when-attempting-to-upgr) that says to put this in:

```
apt-get update --allow-unauthenticated
```

And if that doesn't work to type:

```
apt-get update --allow-insecure-repositories
```

Both of these, unfortunately, give me an error stating that I don't have the correct authorization to do it, despite me being the only account on the device.

There's also [this guide](https://zdoom.org/wiki/Compile_GZDoom_on_Linux) on the ZDoom wiki, but it looks super intimidating. Would it be possible to make something like a batch file (but in bash I guess?) that runs all of the commands without me having to type each one out?

Comment: The two `apt-get` commands should be run with `sudo` in front of them to give you the required authorisation level.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? If you use 16.04 LTS, then there is a [RetroGames PPA](https://launchpad.net/~samoilov-lex/+archive/ubuntu/retrogames/+packages?field.name_filter=gzdoom&field.status_filter=&field.series_filter=) with package...